# $push but not create wrapper to pushed object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have group like this:

```
{
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$conversationId",
                "conversation": {
                    "$push": {"from": {
                            "firstName": "$fromObj.firstName",
                            "lastName": "$fromObj.lastName",
                            "title": "$fromObj.title",
                            "picture": "$fromObj.picture"

                        }, "to": {
                            "firstName": "$toObj.firstName",
                            "lastName": "$toObj.lastName",
                            "title": "$toObj.title",
                            "picture": "$toObj.picture"
                        },"content": "$content"
                        }}

            }

        }
```

And $project(select):

```
{"$project": {
                "conversation": "$conversation"
            }
        }
```

it now pushed details add to separate `coversation object` how can I remove conversation wrapper?

```
{
 _id: "123321",
 conversation: {
   from: {
    ....   
   },
   to: {
    ...
   }
 }
}
```

I need to get something like this:

```
{
 _id: "123321",
 from: {
    ....   
 },
 to: {
    ...
 }
}
```

So just to remove conversation parent object and leave child inside.

Comment: What's your desired output? Can you share some sample documents to test with?

Comment: Edited check it now please

Answer (score 0):

i created the following document :

```
db.test.find().pretty()
{
      "_id" : ObjectId("583c994c30be1871e839d52c"),
      "conversation" : {
              "from" : {
                      "cur" : "USD"
              },
              "to" : {
                      "cur" : "CAD"
              }
      }
}
```

ran the following query :

```
db.valdmir.aggregate((
{"$unwind":"$conversation"},
{"$project":{"from":"$conversation.from","to":"$conversation.to"}}
))
```

my output:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("583c994c30be1871e839d52c"),
 "from" : { "cur" : "USD" }, 
"to" : { "cur" : "CAD" } 
}
```

hope this solves your problem.